# int cannot be dereferenced. Databinding binary operators

Tags: android, primitive-types, android-databinding

I have **"int cannot be dereferenced"** error when I try setup flag using binary operator inside layout using databinding.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="textState"
            type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </data>
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            app:paintFlags="@{checkbox.getPaintFlags() | textState.intValue()}"/>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This order `checkbox.getPaintFlags() | textState.intValue()` of binary operands is interpreted as `((int)checkbox).getPaintFlags()` and it's cause of the error.

But! If your invert order of operands it interpreted properly. And it works!

I was wondered when I find out this feature